# Kendo Upload: sync two conrols upload complete

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui

I have on html page  two kendo upload widgets without autoupload.
When I press button, both controls starts uploading files to the backend.
When all controls sucessfully uploaded files, I need to perform some post processing.

I can subscribe to the complete event, but how do I catch the moment, when both controls are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a count of the completed uploads. Reset it to zero when you start. In the complete event handler (use the same one for each upload widget), increment the counter. When you hit 2, you know both are done.

```
var uploadCount;

onStartUpload: function () {
    uploadCount = 0;
}

uploadComplete: function () {
    uploadCount++;
    if (uploadCount = 2) {
        doPostProcessing();
    }
}
```

You will of course need to check and cater for successful upload, cancelled uploads, re-uploads etc.